# Settings as shared Instance

Tags: swift

I tried to do this so get my settings saved whenever the App moves to the background or gets killed or whatever.
I want to access and set the property "useLimits" all over my App.

Why is it not working?

Is there a better more elegant way to achieve this?

```
import UIKit

class Settings: NSObject
{

    static let sharedInstance = Settings()

    private let kUseLimits = "kUseLimits"

    var useLimits = false

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(Settings.save),
            name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
            object: nil)
        let userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        self.useLimits = userdefaults.boolForKey(kUseLimits)

    }

    deinit
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        save()
    }

    func save()
    {
        let userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userdefaults.setBool(self.useLimits, forKey: kUseLimits)
        userdefaults.synchronize()
    }

    func reset()
    {
        self.useLimits = false
        save()
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the app delegate...

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this will be good:

```
class AppSettings {
  private struct Keys {
    static let useLimits = "AppSttings.useLimits"
  }

  static var useLimits: Bool {
    set {
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: Keys.useLimits)
    }
    get {
      return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Keys.useLimits)
    }
  }

  static func rest() {
    useLimits = false
  }
}
```

P.S. Starting from iOS 8 you don't need to call `synchronize()` in NSUserDefault

P.S.S. `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Keys.useLimits)` will return `false` if there not such object, if you need specific default value please check on object or use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults()`

P.S.S.S. It wont effect your performance much, so you can read from UD and write there just on on the run, but if you want too performance code, you can do something like this:

```
private static var _useLimits: Bool?
static var useLimits: Bool {
  set {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: Keys.useLimits)
    _useLimits = newValue
  }
  get {
    if _useLimits == nil {
      _useLimits = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Keys.useLimits)
    }
    return _useLimits!
  }
}
```

or more elegant for current value:

```
private static var _useLimits: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Keys.useLimits)
static var useLimits: Bool {
  set {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: Keys.useLimits)
    _useLimits = newValue
  }
  get {
    return _useLimits
  }
}
```